# Making a scope variable dynamic in ng-model and controller

Tags: angularjs, pug

I'd like to know how to make scope variables dynamic or perhaps how to append indexes to the end of the variable name. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have the following 2 search boxes (written in Jade - feel free to respond with HTML)

```
.search-bar.col-xs-5
    input.form-control(
        type='text', 
        ng-model='search1', //how to make this part dynamic?
        ng-change='change()', 
        onclick='select()', 
        placeholder='Enter full movie name', 
        autofocus='')
.col-xs-1
    button#submit1.btn.btn-default(type='button' ng-click="save(1)") 
.search-bar.col-xs-5
    input.form-control(type='text', 
        ng-model='search2', 
        ng-change='change()', 
        onclick='select()', 
        placeholder='Enter full movie name', 
        autofocus='')
.col-xs-1
    button#submit2.btn.btn-default(type='button' ng-click="save(2)")
```

As you can see ng-model is "search1" and "search2". So in my Controller I have several functions reacting to these fields. Consider the following:

```
    function fetch() {
        if ($scope.search1) {
        $http.get("http://www.someapi.com/?t=" + $scope.search1)
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.details1 = response;
            });
        };
        if ($scope.search2) {
        $http.get("http://www.someapi.com/?t=" + $scope.search2)
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.details2 = response;
            });
        };
    };

    $scope.save = function(field) {
        var title;
        if (field == 1) {
            title = {
                name: $scope.search1,
                creator: "1",
                date_submitted: Date()

            }
        }
        if (field == 2) {
            title= {
                name: $scope.search2,
                creator: "2",
                date_submitted: Date()

            }
        }

        $http.post("/api/posts", title)

    };
```

Surely there is a better way to approach both those functions. What if I have 10 search fields? I don't want to always use if blocks to determine which field I'm on or what data to store. For example I want basically this (obviously this doesn't work, but the idea of it is what I want):

```
        $http.get("http://www.someapi.com/?t=" + $scope.search + field)
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.details1 = response;
            });
```

and

title = {
                    name: $scope.search + field,
                    fieldid: field,
                    date_submitted: Date()
           }

Sorry this is long winded. Other responses I've found on the subject have been inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

What about declaring the search variable as an Array, so that the view will be something like

```
.search-bar.col-xs-5( ng-repeat="s in searches track by $index")
    input.form-control(
        type='text', 
        ng-model='s',
        ng-change='change()', 
        onclick='select()', 
        placeholder='Enter full movie name', 
        autofocus='')
  .col-xs-1
      button#submit1.btn.btn-default(type='button' ng-click="save($index)")
```

then the controller will have the following

```
$scope.searches = [null, null, null, null] // assuming 4 search criteria
$scope.details = [null, null, null, null]

function fetch() {
  for(s, i in $scope.searches){ // this line is written in coffeescript you can map it to JS
    if (s) {
    $http.get("http://www.someapi.com/?t=" + s)
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.details[i] = response;
        });
    };
  }

};

$scope.save = function(i) {
    var title = {
            name: $scope.searches[i],
            creator: i+1,
            date_submitted: Date()
        }

    $http.post("/api/posts", title)

};
```

Comment: It seems to think s is undefined in this case.